# How to fix unresolved identifier error and correctly call functions in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am new to using Swift and just got my first assignment. The assignment instructions are as follows: Use the map function of the array class to convert an array of integers into the words represented by the integers.  For instance, if your array was: [49] the resulting array should be something like: ["Forty Nine"].  The mapping should handle at least numbers in the thousands.

I am getting a number of errors but the biggest one I cannot figure out is:
main.swift:46:25: error: use of unresolved identifier 'randomArray'
let stringRandomArray = randomArray.map{convertInt(num: $0)}

Aside from this I am getting errors on my function calls in my switch statement. How do you call a function in swift with a variable as the argument? I know my code is extremely messy but I am still getting used to the new language.

```
let singleDigit = [0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two", 3: "Three", 4: "Four", 5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"]
let doubleDigit = [11: "Eleven", 12: "Twelve", 13: "Thirteen", 14: "Fourteen", 15: "Fifteen", 16: "Sixteen", 17: "Seventeen", 18: "Eighteen", 19: "Nineteen"]
let tensMultiples = [10: "Ten", 20: "Twenty", 30: "Thirty", 40: "Fourty", 50: "Fifty", 60: "Sixty", 70: "Seventy", 80: "Eighty", 90: "Ninety"]
let hundreds = [100: "Hundred"]
let thousands = [1000: "Thousand"]


func convertInt(num: Int) -> String{
var length = num.count
var output = ""
    switch length {
        case 1:
            calculateOne(num)
        case 2:
            calculateTwo(num)
        case 3:
            calculateThree(num)
        case 4:
            calculateFour(num)
    }
}

func calculateOne(num: Int) -> String {
    return singleDigit[num]
}

func calculateTwo(num: Int) -> String {
    if num > 10 && num < 20 {
        return doubleDigit[num]
    } else if num % 10 == 0 {
        return tensMultiples[num]
    } else {
        return tensMultiples[num / 10] + doubleDigit[num % 10]
    }
}

func calculateThree(num: Int) -> String {
    return singleDigit[num / 100] + hundreds[100] + calculateTwo[num % (singleDigit[num / 100] + hundreds[100])]
}

func calculateFour(num: Int) -> String {
    return singleDigit[num / 1000] + thousands[1000] + calculateThree[num % (singleDigit[num / 1000] + thousands[1000])]
}

let stringRandomArray = randomArray.map{convertInt(num: $0)}
```

Comment: There are many errors (*missing argument* and *must be unwrapped*) in the code. The `unresolved identifier` one is pretty clear: There is no `randomArray`

Comment: that's because you didn't define `randomArray` with `let` or `var` before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot figure out is: main.swift:46:25: error: use of unresolved identifier 'randomArray' let stringRandomArray = randomArray.map{convertInt(num: $0)}

This error is caused by the fact that there's no such variable declared in the program.
You need to create an array first and then use your function to map its integer values to string values. For this example I just hardcoded the "random" array:

```
let randomArray = [5, 42, 94, 3, 12]
let stringRandomArray = randomArray.map { convertInt(num: $0) }
```

Generating an array of random integer numbers is an interesting task on itself when learning a new language so I've just used a simpler version and generated random numbers in my head :)

> How do you call a function in swift with a variable as the argument?

You simply pass the variable name inside the parentheses:

```
func triple(value: Int) -> Int {
    return value * 3
}

var n = 10
let nTimesThree = triple(value: n) //nTimesThree is now 30
```

I'd also highly recommend to read the [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html). It provides a great introduction into many language features, including functions. Happy learning!

Comment: Thanks so much! I coded a random number generator and made my array. I also changed my function calls but now it is giving me this error all over the place: error: value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'
        return singleDigit[num] 
I've been reading the language guide about unwrapping values and something just is not clicking in my head..

Comment: In your code `singleDigit` is a dictionary with integer keys and string values, in other words it has a type `[Int:String]`. By calling `singleDigit[num]` you're asking the dictionary to return a value that matches the key stored in the variable `num`, but there might not be such key in the dictionary. That's why the returned value is an optional which may have value if such key exists, but will be `nil` otherwise. You need to unwrap the optional in order to access the value, I suggest learning about [Optional Chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html).